# Using possessive when talking about two

Tags: possessives

What's the correct form of writing this possessive sentence:

1. Helena and my birthdays are coming.
2. Helena's and my birthdays are coming.
3. My and Helena's birthdays are coming.

Any links about the grammar rules related can be useful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My birthday** *(the first birthday)* **and Helena's** *(the second birthday - it's implied that we are talking about her birthday since it's not directly specified)* **are** *(because there are two birthdays-not talking about the actual day but the celebration - of which there are two)* **coming**.

Comment: I thought about this, but I think will be more elegant to put my wife's email before. Right? As usual female names come first.

Comment: Then it's _Helena's birthday and mine are coming_